# Which index will speed up the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

In the table of 350 million records, the structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `job_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `lock` mediumint(6) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
    `time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `job_id` (`job_id`),
    KEY `lock` (`lock`),
    KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

What index should I create to speed up the query:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `lock` = 1 WHERE `lock` = 0 ORDER BY `time` ASC LIMIT 500;
```

Comment: Why do you use MyISAM ? if you run this query often, MyISAM have only a table lock. This means that when this query (or some other writes) running nobody else can read or write this table

Comment: @BerndBuffen , what do you advise to use?

Comment: Please don't use unrelated databases tags.

Comment: `ORDER BY ``time`` ASC LIMIT 500` - Why do you have this in an update statement?

Comment: @Dmitry - InnoDB is a storage engine with row level locking. can you please also post the output from **SELECT * FROM `table` PROCEDURE ANALYSE();**, but it can use some time. then we can see the distribution of your data in the table. in the query the table name must in backticks. you cant see it in comment

Comment: @BerndBuffen , I started the query, it is running. Can I create a new InnoDB table in an existing database among the MyISAM tables?

Comment: you can do it with **ALTER TABLE `table` ENGINE InnoDB;** then you direct change your table or you create a new **CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE table; ALTER TABLE `newtable` ENGINE InnoDB; insert into `newtable` select * from `table`;**  After this you can rename the table **RENAME TABLE `table` to `table_org`, `newtable`to `table`;**

Comment: [_Conversion Tips_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb) (MyISAM to InnoDB)

Answer (score 1):

`lock` is declared to be `NULLable`.  Does this mean that the value is often `NULL`?  If so, then there is a nasty problem in MyISAM (not InnoDB) that may lead to 500 additional fragmentation hits.

When a MyISAM row is updated *and* it becomes longer, then the row will not longer fit where it is.  (Now my detailed knowledge gets fuzzy.)  The new row will be put somewhere else and/or it will be broken into two parts, with a link between the parts.  That implies writes in two places.

As Gordon pointed out, any change to any indexed column, `lock` in your case, involved a costly index update -- remove a 'row' from one place in the index's BTree and add a row in another place.

Does `lock` have only values 0 or 1?  Then use `TINYINT` (1 byte), not `MEDIUMINT` (3 bytes).

You should check `MAX(id)`.  If it is clean, id's max will be about 350M (not too close to the limit of 4B).  But if there has been any churn, it may be much closer to the limit.

I, too, advocate switching to InnoDB.  However your 10GB (data+indexes) will grow to 20-30GB in the conversion.

Are you "locking the oldest unlocked" thingies?  Will you then do a select to see what got locked?

If this is too slow, don't do 500 at once, pick a lower number.

With InnoDB, can you avoid locking?  *Perhaps* transactional locking would suffice?

I think we need to see the rest of the environment -- other tables, job "flow", etc.  There may be other things we can suggest.

And I second the motion for `INDEX(lock, time)`.  But when doing so, `DROP` the index on just `lock` as being redundant.

And when converting to InnoDB, do all the index changes *in the same* `ALTER`.  This will run faster than separate passes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I try to transfer the table to InnoDB and conduct the tests of sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
UPDATE `table`
    SET `lock` = 1
    WHERE `lock` = 0
    ORDER BY `time` ASC
    LIMIT 500;
```

The best index is `table(lock, time)`.  Do note, however, that the update also needs to update the index, so you should test how well this works in practice.  Do not make this a clustered index.  That will just slow down the process.

Comment: This key works very long. It seems that due to the fact that the request leads to the update of the same index.